# Cumulative sum of multiple window functions

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the structure:

```
id | date       | player_id | score
--------------------------------------
1  | 2019-01-01 | 1         | 1
2  | 2019-01-02 | 1         | 1
3  | 2019-01-03 | 1         | 0
4  | 2019-01-04 | 1         | 0
5  | 2019-01-05 | 1         | 1
6  | 2019-01-06 | 1         | 1
7  | 2019-01-07 | 1         | 0
8  | 2019-01-08 | 1         | 1
9  | 2019-01-09 | 1         | 0
10 | 2019-01-10 | 1         | 0
11 | 2019-01-11 | 1         | 1
```

I want to create two more columns, 'total_score', 'last_seven_days'.

total_score is a rolling sum of the player_id score

last_seven_days is the score for the last seven days including to and prior to the date

I have written the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id,
    date,
    player_id,
    score,
    sum(score) OVER all_scores AS all_score,
    sum(score) OVER last_seven AS last_seven_score
   FROM scores
  WINDOW all_scores AS (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 
last_seven AS (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING);
```

and get the following output:

```
id | date       | player_id | score | all_score | last_seven_score   
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2019-01-01 | 1         | 1     |           | 
2  | 2019-01-02 | 1         | 1     | 1         | 1
3  | 2019-01-03 | 1         | 0     | 2         | 2
4  | 2019-01-04 | 1         | 0     | 2         | 2
5  | 2019-01-05 | 1         | 1     | 2         | 2
6  | 2019-01-06 | 1         | 1     | 3         | 3
7  | 2019-01-07 | 1         | 0     | 4         | 4
8  | 2019-01-08 | 1         | 1     | 4         | 4
9  | 2019-01-09 | 1         | 0     | 5         | 4
10 | 2019-01-10 | 1         | 0     | 5         | 3
11 | 2019-01-11 | 1         | 1     | 5         | 3
```

I have realised that I need to change this

`last_seven AS (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)`

to instead of being 7, to use some sort of date format because just having the number 7 will introduce errors.

i.e. it would be nice to be able to do `date - 2days` or `date - 6days`

I also would like to add columns such as 3 months, 6 months, 12 months later down the track and so need it to be able to be dynamic.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=33e2e34dd1d0b318922c1bcb4e4bbf73)

Comment: On Postgres 11 it is really simple to achieve. But your fiddle is for Pg10. Is it possible for you to upgrade? Or do you need a Pg10 solution?

Comment: Is there always exactly one record per day and player?

Comment: Can be for PG 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=80548f0ca26781e18a6f9e5a352007d4)

---

Solution for **Postgres 11+**:

Using `RANGE interval` as @LaurenzAlbe did

---

Solution for **Postgres <11**:

(just presenting the "days" part, the "all_scores" part is the same)

Joining the table against itself on the `player_id` and the relevant `date` range:

```
SELECT s1.*,
    (SELECT SUM(s2.score)
     FROM scores s2
     WHERE s2.player_id = s1.player_id
         AND s2."date" BETWEEN s1."date" - interval '7 days' AND s1."date" - interval '1 days')
FROM scores s1
```

Comment: how can I get a `row_number(*)` for just the `last_seven`, so that it would refresh back to 1 when it reaches the start of the new interval?

Comment: @LukeByrne: I don't understand what you trying to achieve with row_number()

Comment: I will put together a new question and db fiddle, it will be clearer.

Comment: Added a tick to the answer, does that close it

Comment: @LukeByrne The green hook accepts and closes it (can be done only with one answer), the upvote is for internal credentials of the replier (can and should be given to every good answer)

Comment: You got any capacity to look at this question, its a modified version of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952450/cumulative-sum-of-multiple-window-functions-v3

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a window by `RANGE`:

```
last_seven AS (PARTITION BY player_id
               ORDER BY date
               RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '7 days' PRECEDING
                         AND INTERVAL '1 day' PRECEDING)
```

This solution will work only from v11 on.

Comment: This only works for Pg11 and higher. The TO's fiddle is for Pg10. That's why I asked ;)

Comment: @Laurenz Albe You got any capacity to look at this question, its a modified version of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952450/cumulative-sum-of-multiple-window-functions-v3