# Cumulative sum of multiple window functions V3

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
id    |     date       | player_id  | score | all_games | all_wins     |    n_games  | n_wins
============================================================================================
6747  |   2018-08-10 |      1       |   0   |   1       |              |    1        |      
6751  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   2       |   0          |    2        |      
6764  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   3       |   0          |    3        |      
6783  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   4       |   0          |    4        |      
6804  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   5       |   0          |    5        |      
6821  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   6       |   0          |    6        |      
6828  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   7       |   0          |    7        |      
17334 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   8       |   0          |    8        |      0
17363 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   9       |   0          |    9        |      0
17398 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   10      |   0          |    10       |      0
17403 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   11      |   0          |    11       |      0
17409 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   12      |   0          |    12       |      0
33656 |     2018-09-13 |    1       |   0   |   13      |   0          |    13       |      0
33687 |     2018-09-13 |    1       |   0   |   14      |   0          |    14       |      0
45393 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   15      |   0          |    15       |      0
45402 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   16      |   0          |    16       |      0
45422 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   1   |   17      |   0          |    17       |      0
45453 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   18      |   1          |    18       |      0
45461 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   19      |   1          |    19       |      0
45474 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   20      |   1          |    20       |      0
57155 |     2018-10-11 |    1       |   0   |   21      |   1          |    21       |      1
57215 |     2018-10-11 |    1       |   0   |   22      |   1          |    22       |      1
57225 |     2018-10-11 |    1       |   0   |   23      |   1          |    23       |      1
69868 |     2018-10-25 |    1       |   0   |   24      |   1          |    24       |      1
```

The issue that I now need to solve is that I need n_games to be a rolling count of the last number of games per day, i.e. a user can play multiple games per day, as present it is just the same as row_number(*) OVER all_games

The other issues is that the column n_wins only does a sum(*) of the rolling windows wins for the day, so if a user wins a couple of games early on in day, that will not be added to the n_wins column until the next day.

I have the example [*DEMO*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4bdcc98c888eb361e37d84dc9a669422):

I have tried this query

```
SELECT id,
   date,
   player_id,
   score,
   row_number(*) OVER all_races AS all_games,
   sum(score) OVER all_races AS all_wins,
   row_number(*) OVER last_n AS n_games,
   sum(score) OVER last_n AS n_wins
  FROM scores  
 WINDOW 
 all_races AS (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 
 last_n AS (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY date ASC RANGE BETWEEN interval '7 days' PRECEDING AND interval '1 day' PRECEDING);
```

Ideally I need a query that will output something like this table

```
id    |     date       | player_id  | score | all_games | all_wins     |    n_games  | n_wins
============================================================================================
6747  |   2018-08-10 |      1       |   0   |   1       |              |    1       |   
6751  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   2       |   0          |    2       |   
6764  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   3       |   0          |    3       |       
6783  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   4       |   0          |    4       |   
6804  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   5       |   0          |    5       |   
6821  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   6       |   0          |    6       |   
6828  |     2018-08-10 |    1       |   0   |   7       |   0          |    7       |   
17334 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   8       |   0          |    1       |   0
17363 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   9       |   0          |    2       |   0
17398 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   10      |   0          |    3       |   0
17403 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   11      |   0          |    4       |   0
17409 |     2018-08-23 |    1       |   0   |   12      |   0          |    5       |   0
33656 |     2018-09-13 |    1       |   1   |   13      |   1          |    6       |   0
33687 |     2018-09-13 |    1       |   0   |   14      |   1          |    7       |   1
45393 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   15      |   1          |    1       |   1
45402 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   16      |   1          |    2       |   1
45422 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   1   |   17      |   1          |    3       |   1
45453 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   18      |   2          |    4       |   2
45461 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   19      |   2          |    5       |   2
45474 |     2018-09-27 |    1       |   0   |   20      |   2          |    6       |   1
57155 |     2018-10-11 |    1       |   0   |   21      |   2          |    7       |   1
57215 |     2018-10-11 |    1       |   0   |   22      |   2          |    1       |   1
57225 |     2018-10-11 |    1       |   0   |   23      |   2          |    2       |   1
69868 |     2018-10-25 |    1       |   0   |   24      |   2          |    3       |   1
```

Comment: Don't do this in a query, do it in procedural code. Use a cursor to go through the rows in the correct order and calculate the values you need. That will be so much simpler. SQL isn't made for procedural requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the heads Laurenz, I am pulling it out into Pandas so I will do it there.